# React and slick: resonsive is not working

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

I am trying to add slick carousel in react app, so far slick sliding works fine but the responsive part does not work, Please check this code if I am doing something wrong

```
$('.slick-container1').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 900,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      });
```

The same code works totally fine with plain html design but not with react.

Comment: If you are seeing this, I prefer use react slick version of this, it is easier to implement instead of adding <script> tag in react app